# how to set up android:authorities for testing?

Tags: android, testing, android-manifest, authority

I have the following source code:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, activity.getPackageName() + ".file", file);
```

and the following in the Manifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="app.domain.app-name.file"
    ...
</provider>
```

which works correctly when the app is running. However, when running instrumented tests, activity.getPackageName() returns my app's package name with ".test" appended to it causing the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority app.domain.app-name.test.file
```

What is the correct setup that works in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `android:authorities` to this:

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.file"
```